# How could a character verify they aren't crazy after accidental time travel

Tags: time-travel, memory, paradox

A 40-year-old character from today (April 2020) with a good memory is unexpectedly transported back in time 30 years. One instant he is at work, the next he is back in grade school in his 10-year-old body, sitting at his desk, confused at what happened.

After overcoming the initial shock and figuring out where (and when) he is, he still has vivid, undeniable memories of **the next 30 years**, clear enough that he can convince himself he has lived into the future. He has no doubt the date *was* April 2020 before he appeared in grade school.

Finding his 2019 cell phone in his pocket and his 2018 laptop in his backpack, he begins to wonder if he has gone crazy, or is hallucinating his time travel when he has such obviously modern gear that he is intimately familiar with and uses with native proficiency. Thoughts of "am I in a hospital in a coma?", "is this a dream?", or "did I have a bad reaction to medication and I am hallucinating?" are at the forefront of his mind. He sets on a quest to determine if he REALLY is back in 1990.

I am not worried about how to convince others that he has memories from the future, as that seems pretty easy to do over time with things like sporting event outcomes, political election results, natural disasters, songs, movies, other media, a 10-year-old knowing college-level calculus, etc. That's not the concern.

This is a similar initial premise as [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/concealing-your-accidental-backwards-time-travel-finding-other-backwards-travel) except my character will not try to hide his time travel, at all.

I am deliberately ignoring the time-travel unraveling effect of "if he changes minor things, major historical things could change too". That's not part of the question.

Money is not an issue for his quest, as he has a good memory and making money in the stock market is no big deal.

The question is how can my character *definitively* figure out if he is hallucinating or not? Is there some logic game he could play to know **know** if he is hallucinating or has truly time traveled?

Comment: This looks more like a question about a plot point, rather than a question about building a fictional world. Such questions are off topic for this site.

Comment: This is generally unsolvable. However, the protagonist may be able to examine and reject some specific forms of mental disorder.

Comment: You are discussing the fundamental issue at the core of the [Life on Mars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478942/) tv series along with it's spin-off, [Ashes to Ashes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1008108/?ref_=tt_sims_tt).  In 5 years of episodes across the two separate series, they explored many possible explanations, but never got past your fundamental question.

Comment: Quick continuity check...   For the laptop to be in his backpack in the past, he must have put it in a comparable backpack in the future.  Your audience might have no trouble believing in time travel, but a 40-year old wearing a backpack is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Good question. I was imagining him siting at his desk at desk at work, with his laptop in a laptop bag next to him, not wearing it. When he stands up from going back in time, it is sitting next to him as well. So the backpack he has is a modern one. Didn't worry too much about the bag.